# Select where date without time

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite, now how can I Select a query if I have a timestamp column that has this value for example `07:00 06/03/13` but I want only to select where timestamp `06/03/13`.

This is my example of my query..

```
select 
    timestamp, pname 
from 
    attendance 
where 
    timestamp between `06/01/13` and `06/10/13`
```

Comment: parse it using simpleDateFormat.parse in to a string

Answer (score 4):

Use `date`

```
select timestamp, pname 
from attendance 
where date(timestamp) = '2013-03-06'
```

Answer (score 1):

When filtering on a timestamp column, you want this logic.

```
where YourField >= TheStartOfYourRange
and YourField < TheDayAfterTheEndOfYourRange
```

This is equivalent to the two answers that use the date() function, but will generally perform faster.  Using functions in the where clause usually slows down production, especially on indexed fields.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite support function `date`, which can be used to get the date part of a timestamp.  For example:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date(timestamp_col) = '2013-05-20'
```

See [SQLite date and time functions documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for more info.