# Select between varchar as a date returns null

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, varchar

I have a table `attendance_sheet` and it has column `string_date` which is a varchar.

This is inside my table data.

```
id | string_date  | pname 
1  | '06/03/2013' | 'sam'
2  | '08/23/2013' | 'sd'
3  | '11/26/2013' | 'rt'
```

I try to query it using this range.

```
SELECT * FROM attendance_sheet
where string_date between '06/01/2013' and '12/31/2013'
```

then it returns the data.. but when I try to query it using this

```
SELECT * FROM attendance_sheet
where string_date between '06/01/2013' and '03/31/2014'
```

it did not return any results...

It can be fixed without any changing the column type for example the `string_date` which is a `varchar` will be changed into a `date`?

Does anyone has an Idea about my case?
any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance ..

Comment: You should have edited your old answer and not ask the same thing twice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [select where date without time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648209/select-where-date-without-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`strftime`](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DateAndTimeFunctions)

```
SELECT * FROM attendance_sheet
where strftime(string_date,'%m/%d/%Y') between '2013-06-01' and '2013-31-21'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer juergen but I got this error `no such function: STR_TO_DATE` on my sqlite browser

Answer (score 0):

The reason this:

```
where string_date between '06/01/2013' and '03/31/2014'
```

does not return any results is that '06' is greater than '03'.  It's essentially the same as using this filter.

```
where SomeField between 'b' and 'a'
```

The cause of this problem is a poorly designed database.  Storing dates as strings is a bad idea.  Juergen has shown you a function that might help you, but since your field is varchar, values like, 'fred', 'barney', and 'dino' are perfectly valid.  The Str_to_date() function won't work very well with those.

If you are able to change your database, do so.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do string comparisons correctly, you have to change your database so that the most significant field of the date comes first, i.e., use the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.